# Multiplying without the multiplication operator in python

Tags: python, operators, multiplication

How do I write a python script that multiplies `x * y` without using the multiplication operator? I know that basically you should have:

```
def multi():
    x = raw_input('x is: ')
    y = raw_input('y is: ')
    z = #(x + x) y times
    return z

multi()
```

Comment: The easiest way is to repeatedly add.

Comment: Go old-school and use logarithms :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [reduce](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) which does x*y in the way you describe:

```
x = raw_input('x is: ')
y = raw_input('y is: ')
reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, [x]*y)
```

This will calculate ((x+x)+x)... y times.

EDIT to explain what reduce does:

The 1st argument is a function taking exactly 2 arguments, describing what to do at each iteration.

`lambda x,y: x+y` is just a function taking 2 arguments and adding them together. As if you wrote:

```
def my_operation(x, y):
    return x + y
```

The 2nd argument is the input data, for example `[1, 4, 2, 8, 9]`.

`reduce` will iterate over your input data, starting with 1 and 4. This is passed to your function which will return 5. Then 5 and 2 are passed to your function,...
So the calculation will be `((((1+4)+2)+8)+9)`

So if your input list is [x, x, x..., x] of length y (i.e. `[x]*y`), you will get the result you want, calculated in the way you described.

Comment: At least my answer followed the *letter* of the question :P

Comment: @seb, in all honesty I have no idea as to what's going on here... reduce, lambda and the : stuff is way over my head... do you mind explaining what actions are being performed?

Answer (score 1):

```
x.__mul__(y)
operator.mul(x, y)
```

Comment: Cheeky, but I would venture to guess that this person's instructor would consider this method to be another form of the multiplication operator.

Answer (score 0):

With [sum](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) and range or [xrange](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange):

```
z = sum(x for _ in xrange(y))
```

It can of course work the other way around, and effectively does `x+x` `y` times as you requested.

This works essentialy the same as doing:

```
z = 0
for _ in range(y):
    z += x
```

Comment: Except xrange isn't in Python 3.x.  There it's more cleanly called "range".

Comment: Although Python 3.x doesn't have `raw_input()` either.

Comment: @user1277476 I didn't know all answers have to comply to both 2.x and 3.x. In any case, it says "range or xrange" right there.

Comment: @korem what do you mean by "for _ in"

Comment: @SydneyLing it's the same as doing `for i in ...`, except `_` is usually used for variables which aren't later used (as in this case)

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.x you can use this code to solve the same problem.
Knowing that 5*5 is == 5+5+5+5+5....with that idea in mind...

```
a = int(input("Intro a number: "))
b = int(input("Intro a second number: "))
for i in range(1,a):
    b = b+a
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

How do I write a python script that multiplies x * y without using the multiplication operator? you can use this code to solve the same problem

```
a = int(input("Intro a number: "))
b = int(input("Intro a second number: "))
c=b
for i in range(1,a):
    b = b+c
    print(b)
```